# How do I implicitly import commonly used modules?

Tags: haskell

Recently I've been writing a lot of scripts in Haskell. It's quite an enjoyable experience as it is one of the most concise languages I've ever touched.

One thing that bothers me a lot though, is that I have to type in the same `import`s for every script I write, and there's a set of modules I use almost everytime, like

```
import Control.Monad as MO
import Data.ByteString.Lazy as BS
import Data.Char as CH
import Data.Csv as C
import Data.Csv.Streaming as CS
import Data.Foldable as FOLD
import Data.Functor as F
import Data.List as L
import Data.List.Split as LS
import Data.Text.Lazy as T
import Data.Text.Lazy.IO as TI
import Data.Vector as V
import Debug.Trace as TR
import Prelude as P
```

I mean I could copy and paste them every time, but is there a way I can make these tedious imports implicit? Just like how `Prelude` is imported implicitly?

Comment: One option is to set up some sort of IDE like auto-import feature, in addition to a "stock template", and then simply collapse the imports section out of sight.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One option for some purposes is to write one or more "kitchen sink" modules for your own use and just import that every time. Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to do much good when it comes to *named* or *qualified* imports. Another option is to use `{-# LANGUAGE CPP #-}` to `#include` some stock header pieces.

However, I wouldn't particularly recommend any of these options. Just keep a "stock template" around with your favorite GHC extensions and module imports, and teach your text editor to use it. Don't forget to prune away the stuff you don't actually need.

Comment: Though I generally dislike templates (the ones you copy around, not the Template Haskell kind), I agree that a template is probably the most reasonable way to start with an import list. The danger is, of course, that you can end up with modules that import a lot of stuff which is not really needed.

Comment: @leftaroundabout There's the `-fwarn-unused-imports` option.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, that's better than the kitchen sink module, which will permanently suppress the warning!